# $\sup_t |T(t)|<+\infty$ implies $\sup_t |T(t)^*|<+\infty$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Let $X$ be a Banach space. $T(t)$ a family of bounded operators for $t\in\mathbb{R}$. $T(t)^*$ is the adjoint operator of $T(t)$.

If $\sup_t |T(t)^*|<+\infty$ , then by Hahn-Banach, there's a $x^*\in X ^*$ with $|x^*|=1$ such that $|T(t)x|=\langle x^*,T(t)x \rangle$, we have then
$$|T(t)x|=|\langle x^*,T(t)x \rangle|=|\langle T(t)^* x^*,x \rangle|\leq |T(t)^*||x|$$
and we have $\sup_t |T(t)|<+\infty.$

My question is the converse i.e. if $\sup_t |T(t)|<+\infty$ when do we have $\sup_t |T(t)^*|<+\infty$ ?

Note: As David Mitra mentioned we have even $|T(t)|=|T(t)|^*$.

Comment: A bounded operator and its adjoint always have the same norm.

Comment: @DavidMitra can you give a reference where I can find this result or even a proof ?

Comment: Let $T:X\rightarrow Y$ be bounded. We have $T^*y^*=y^*T$. That $\Vert T^*\Vert\le \Vert T\Vert$ follows easily from this. To prove the reverse inequality, use the fact that for any $x\in X$, $\Vert Tx\Vert=\sup_{y^*\in B(Y^*)}|y^*(Tx)|$.

Comment: A proof is given in article VI.2.2 in Dunford and Schwartz, *Linear Operators, Part 1*. I imagine you can find it in any Functional Analysis text that treats adjoint operators.

Comment: I just figured out how to do it, it's even easier then to the other implications.

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved in comments: $\|T^*\|=\|T\|$ for every bounded linear operator between normed spaces. In fact, we only need the easier part here: $\|T^*\|\le \|T\|$, which comes directly from the fact that $T^*$ acts on linear functionals by composing them with $T$.